# Salabim not running on python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the package salabim but I get a very weird error. I am currently using python 3.9 on a MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.4

This is the sample code I am using

```
import salabim as sim


class Car(sim.Component):
    def process(self):
        while True:
            yield self.hold(1)


env = sim.Environment(trace=True)
Car()
env.run(till=5)
```

and this is the error

```
username@My-MacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/username/Desktop/Car.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Car.py", line 11, in <module>
    env = sim.Environment()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salabim/salabim.py", line 4662, in __init__
    self.view = _AnimateIntro()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salabim/salabim.py", line 4434, in __init__
    self.setup(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salabim/salabim.py", line 18276, in setup
    self.model_lights_pname = gl.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT'
```

Comment: Looks like it can't load OpenGL. Have you checked that it can?

Comment: Based on the source code, `gl` is set to `None` if `import OpenGL.GL as gl` fails. You need to have [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) installed in order for that import to work. Have you installed it?

Comment: @RandomDavis I think I have it installed. If I run this command on terminal ```pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate``` it gives me Requirement already satisfied

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry I am not very familiar with these issues. How could I check that?

Comment: @gapansi99 are you running scripts in the same environment you're installing `pip` packages to? If you use `pip3` instead does it work? When installing `PyOpenGL` via `pip` does it give any error messages?

Comment: @RandomDavis how can I check I am using the same environment? I installed python 3.9 front python.org and I have been installing everything with pip3. This is what I get ```username@user-MacBook-Pro ~ % pip3 install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL_accelerate in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.1.5)```

Comment: @gapansi99 In that case I think you should just make a script with `import OpenGL.GL as gl`, `import OpenGL.GLU as glu` and `import OpenGL.GLUT as glut`, then see if you get any errors. I'm not 100% sure how to determine if the environment you're installing packages to is the same one you're executing scripts from.

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in version 21.1.1, which is corrected now.
Please reinstall salabim.
May I suggest subscribing to the salabim Google user group (see [www.salabim.org](http://www.salabim.org))